# External CSS library not importing via custom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cdn, erpnext

In ERPNEXT i am using custom script to load some external libraries using $.getScript .
JS libraries are being loaded but css aren't . Hope to get some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getScript will load only script files. For css you can use something like this.

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "your css file link"
}).appendTo("head");
```